# Java scanner class - What to do in C#

Tags: c#, java, java.util.scanner

```
public void checkInt(Scanner MemberNrSC)
    {
        MemberNrSC = new Scanner(txtMemberNr.getText());
        while (!MemberNrSC.hasNextInt())
        {
            string correctedMemberNr = Interaction.InputBox(null,"Medlemsnummer skal være et nummer, indtast det rigtige");

            if (correctedMemberNr == null)
            {
                MemberNrCancelled = true;
                break;
            }
            txtMemberNr.setText(correctedMemberNr);

            MemberNrSC = new Scanner(txtMemberNr.getText());
            MemberNrCancelled = false;
        }
    }
```

This is my java checker, for if there is only numbers in the textbox..

But as there is no scanner in C# - how would i get this method converted correct?
I have my other methods needing a scanner class - but i was hoping i could have some help in here.

BTW: i am using a visual basic inputbox - as i do not know if there is a similar way in C#.

Thanks in advance ;-)

/Rasmus
Denmark

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/722270/465053).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string Str = txtMemberNr.Text.Trim();

            double Num;

            bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);

            if (isNum)
            {
              // CODE IS HERE
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Brugernavn skal kun indeholde tal, prøv igen!", "advarsel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

This was the most simple way - checking whether or not there is an int/string in the textbox field.
I was hoping that you/or someone who have option for making this solved.

Thank you for your help - but i could not make it work as wanted - even though there was good use of the scanner.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe

```
class Scanner : System.IO.StringReader
{
  string currentWord;

  public Scanner(string source) : base(source)
  {
     readNextWord();
  }

  private void readNextWord()
  {
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     char nextChar;
     int next;
     do
     {
        next = this.Read();
        if (next < 0)
           break;
        nextChar = (char)next;
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar))
           break;
        sb.Append(nextChar);
     } while (true);
     while((this.Peek() >= 0) && (char.IsWhiteSpace((char)this.Peek())))
        this.Read();
     if (sb.Length > 0)
        currentWord = sb.ToString();
     else
        currentWord = null;
  }

  public bool hasNextInt()
  {
     if (currentWord == null)
        return false;
     int dummy;
     return int.TryParse(currentWord, out dummy);
  }

  public int nextInt()
  {
     try
     {
        return int.Parse(currentWord);
     }
     finally
     {
        readNextWord();
     }
  }

  public bool hasNextDouble()
  {
     if (currentWord == null)
        return false;
     double dummy;
     return double.TryParse(currentWord, out dummy);
  }

  public double nextDouble()
  {
     try
     {
        return double.Parse(currentWord);
     }
     finally
     {
        readNextWord();
     }
  }

  public bool hasNext()
  {
     return currentWord != null;
  }
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/722524/1714342

Comment: I'm sorry.. it now that long ago a changed from 7 1 year of Java programming,i'm a computer science student, now changing for C# after the summer holidays..But my 18 lines of method in java - is that really almost 80 lines i C#.. or is that just a "general" checker.. i have a bit hard seeing through the code.. ;-(

Comment: This code is implementation of Scanner in C#, you do not need to put this in your method, it will be in another file, and you need to reference it just like you referenced Scanner in Java (same usage). If you have any other questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> Scanner(this string tgt, char delim)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in tgt)
        {
            if (c == delim)
            {
                yield return sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
            }
            else sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
```