# Any alternative in C# similar to Java's nextInt() to extract int from string, without using Split()?

Tags: c#

The `Split(' ')` method for example stores the resulting values as, say an array. This is not so convenient for some tasks. Firstly, I don't want to store those values in an array since I need to access each value only once. Secondly, for example if I want to convert those `string` values to `int` then I have to parse to `int` while looping through all the elements of the array once again. Java's `nextInt()` seems to help. Is there any alternative in C#?
Note: The string contains proper int values that can be extracted.

Example:

```
string test = "12 3 56 77 0"
```

Comment: What you're really asking about is Java's `Scanner` class; and there isn't something built-in to .NET to do that.  Should be easy to write though :)

Comment: Smells like not normalized data-structure. :)

Comment: *"This is not so convenient for some tasks. Firstly, I don't want to store those values in an array since I need to access each value only once."* So what if you don't *need* to store? You can say that it's wasteful, but how is it not convenient? And really, writing `.Select(int.Parse)` to convert to integers is not the end of the world.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I believe it's [already been written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722270/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-scanner-class-in-c-sharp-for-strings).

Comment: Well Jon, I was thinking about the memory allocation too. Not so sure though.

Comment: @user1191177 Memory is cheap nowadays. Well, that clearly does not mean that you need to put everything inside and don't optimize at all but worrying about having only one item int instead of four, is just micro-optimization.

Comment: Does the string always contain 5 integers? Then do you use those integers in a calculation?

Comment: var x = values.Split(' ').Select<string,int>(p => Int32.Parse(p));

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 unfortunately you closed the q, the answer in the linked thread is fine, but really, do your really have to write so much code to replace a Select(Int.parse)? wtf... Look at the Scanner code in java, it is very complex, in terms of performance and everything I'm pretty sure the simple split and parse is way better...

Comment: @Ela - The point of closing is to consolidate answers into a single location, rather than scattering them all over the place. If you feel you have a better solution, please answer the duplicate question.

Comment: @Ela - Your solution above was [already proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/722284/211627) on the duplicate question. You might wan to upvote it.

Comment: yep fair enough
btw, just did a quick test with the scanner code posted in this thread. String length of 100000 integers took the scanner 145ms, a simple select and cast (AND iterating over all elements) took 29ms ;)

Comment: @Ela - To be fair, the posted Scanner code is significantly more powerful and flexibile than the select and cast you are suggesting. It is able to retrieve ints or doubles, and can be easily expanded to include other types, such as dates. And a difference of 115 ms on 100,000 items seems like micro-managing performance. At that level, I'd ask myself which is easier to maintain, not which is faster.