# Is there a visual-studio/C# class equivalent to the Scanner(System.in) class in java?

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, java.util.scanner, translate

I have been trying to **input values** into my program to be able to **store and use** the inputs of the user. This is easily done in java because one can just create a Scanner class and use it like so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args){
     static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("\nEnter id number:");
     int id = sc.nextInt();

     System.out.print("\nEnter name:");
     int name = sc.nextString();
}
```

However, when it comes to **implementing** the same idea in C# there seems to be no equivalent class that can be used. *Is there such a class in the system files that could do this?*

If there isn't then are there any **methods** that would be **compatible with C# / visual studio** that accomplish this same feature (like the keyboard class used in java)? Preferably methods that can be implemented in a separate class?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent to the Scanner class in C# for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722270/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-scanner-class-in-c-sharp-for-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement anything man. Just use

```
Console.WriteLine(), Console.ReadLine() & Console.ReadKey()
```

So to answer your question, equivalent of Scanner in C# would be Console

Comment: I use those methods to output text not to read and store what the user inputted. I need a way to read and store what the user inputs during the program's runtime.

Comment: I only did a quick jaunt through a C# tutorial, but this is almost certainly not correct.  `ReadLine()` does just that, reads lines, and not much else. The Java `Scanner` is a fairly powerful and free-form parser, very different than simply reading lines.  It's not really even close.

Comment: I added ReadLIne() because it part of the console class. In any case if you look at the Console class it will suffice. But if you want to get complicated there are ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Console.ReadLine()` to read and store Input to any variable in C#.
for example :

```
using System;
public class GFG{
    static public void Main (){
        //Code
        string message = "What is your name?";
        string myName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello! " + myName);
    }
}
```